# late code evaluation with late variable binding?

Tags: python, late-binding, late-bound-evaluation

You can postpone code execution :

```
In [12]: v = 5

In [13]: e = ' v * 2 '

In [14]: eval(e)
Out[14]: 10
```

I would like to do late evaluation of normal python code w/o assigning it to a string ?

Is there a technique to do this ? closures ?  `__call__` ?

---

another example :

```
In [15]: b = bitarray('10110')

In [16]: p = Pipe(lambda x : x * 2 )

In [17]: e = ' b | p '

In [18]: eval(e)
Out[18]: bitarray('1011010110')
```

i'm trying to build something like diagram/pipe of execution flow similar  TensorFlow & keras and then pass the data and collect the result... it is abit more complicated than that because the flow is not straght-forward ...

Comment: A fancy use of `@property` inside a custom class sounds like it could work. I can't think of a graceful way of doing this though.

Answer (score 2):

The usual way to do this is with a function.

```
def e():
    return v * 2

>>> v = 5
>>> e()
10
>>> v = 6
>>> e()
12
```

I must also say that I'm not in favor of functions that don't take their input as explicit parameters. Grabbing a global is cheating.

Comment: it is obvious ;) .. thinking if this solves my problem ... have to do some experiments ..